# How to select from code primeng listbox?

Tags: angular, listbox, primeng

Is it possible to select 2 options from code using listbox? When the component loads I would like to have the two options already selected.

Answer (score -2):

[Alpaca.js](http://www.alpacajs.org/documentation.html) (which builds forms) allows for [multiselects](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/select.html) in forms, in which a user is presented a dropdown with checkboxes. It should integrate with Angular without issue.

The below code is from their documentation (although I recommend looking at the demo for the associated code):

```
$("#field4").alpaca({
    "data": ["Vanilla", "Chocolate"],
    "options": {
        "label": "Ice cream",
        "helper": "Guess my favorite ice cream?",
        "type": "select",
        "multiple": true, // turns on multiselect dropdown
        "size": 3,
        "dataSource": "/data/icecream-list.json"
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP wants a primeng/angular answer. And your answer just 'should' work with Angular. You don't even know if it does.